# What is the difference between fuel exhaustion and starvation?

Tags: emergency, fuel, terminology, phraseology

Is there any technical difference between fuel *exhaustion* and *starvation*? And what does it mean if a pilot says he has a "fuel shortage"?

Answer (score 13):

Fuel *exhaustion* means there is no more fuel on board the aircraft. Fuel *starvation* means there is fuel somewhere, but it isn't available to the engine(s) for any one of a number of reasons: pilot error, blocked fuel lines or valves, malfunctioning fuel pumps etc. You can read a study of exhaustion and starvation incidents [here](https://www.atsb.gov.au/media/43380/Fuel_exhaustion_and_starvation.pdf).

A "fuel shortage" isn't a formal aviation phrase as far as I know, but "minimum fuel" is a formal phrase with a specific meaning. This is from [the FAA's AIM 5-5-15](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf):

> 1. Advise ATC of your minimum fuel status when your fuel supply has reached a state where, upon reaching destination, you cannot accept
>      any undue delay.
> 2. Be aware this is not an emergency situation, but merely an advisory that indicates an emergency situation is possible should any undue
>      delay occur.
> 3. On initial contact the term “minimum fuel” should be used after stating call sign.
>
>    **EXAMPLE**− *Salt Lake Approach, United 621, “minimum
>      fuel.”*

[This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24836/62) has some more information.

Comment: I would opine that fuel *exhaustion* would be one cause of fuel *starvation*

Answer (score 1):

I imagine fuel exhaustion means you've run out of fuel. Fuel starvation doesn't necessarily mean you've run out of fuel, just that your engines aren't getting. Perhaps from a clogged filter or line.