# What is the procedure after a missed approach at the destination alternate since alternate fuel does not contain a missed app. at the alternate?

Tags: airline-operations, emergency, easa-regulations, emergency-procedures

I am currently studying the fuel policy planning criteria for ATPL EASA(A) and i just learnt that the alternate fuel does NOT comprise the missed approach at the alternate destination aerodrome; in case of such a situation and without contingency fuel (imagine that is already used during trip), what is the procedure then since that I probably have to use the final reserve fuel? I guess that I should declare an emergency, how would it be declared?

Comment: This scenario highlights the importance of selecting an alternate where a successful approach is certain. It is not a formality.

Answer (score 7):

Let's assume you started exactly with ICAO minimum fuel required (as explained in [What are the ICAO fuel reserve requirements?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3740/what-are-the-icao-fuel-reserve-requirements)):

- **Taxi fuel** Let's assume you used all of it at your departure airport.
- **Trip fuel** Used for the flight to the destination airport.
- **Contingency fuel** Let's assume this was used in a holding pattern at the destination.
- **Alternate fuel** Used for a go around at the destination and the subsequent flight to the alternate airport.
- **Final reserve** Not used yet.
- **Additional fuel** Let's assume you did not take any.

Under these assumptions you would be using the **Final reserve** fuel for your go around at the alternate airport. At this point you **should** declare an emergency (see [Do I have to declare an emergency if I cut into fuel reserves?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24836/do-i-have-to-declare-an-emergency-if-i-cut-into-fuel-reserves)) by broadcasting

> MAYDAY, MAYDAY, MAYDAY, FUEL

as explained in [What is the correct phraseology for declaring a fuel emergency?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33665/what-is-the-correct-phraseology-for-declaring-a-fuel-emergency). ATC will then assist you to get to any suitable airport as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is fully the pilot responsibilities; if he has a fuel quantity problem, or if he believes that again a missed approach may occur, **prior** to commencing the alternate approach, he must make a specific request to ATC in the event that one occurs. Such a request may include heading and altitude instructions to avoid in-flight delays (such as holds) and efficiently maneuver the aircraft into position for the next approach.